# android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" Not working android

Tags: android, themes, android-manifest

I declare my activity in manifest file like following.

```
<activity 
        android:name=".SiteView" 
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I declare activity with Fullscreen theame. But its not working.

I also use second way for Fullscreen like following.

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But no success. Please help me to find this.

Comment: @hotveryspicy means? App works on api level 8.

Comment: its not working in which version of android?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solve it by using by declaring fullscreen theame at application level.

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change theme into this: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:-

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
```